# Configure Thunderbird to use google contacts for suggestions

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, contacts

How can I configure Thunderbird to make suggestions on partial e-mail addresses or names while composing an e-mail?

I already have imported my google contacts as an address book, but it appears that Thunderbird will only make suggestions from the local address book.

Comment: You need to use an extension for that. Like this one, for example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/?src=cb-dl-popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure in Thunderbird preferences, composition options, addressing tab, that address auto-completion has enabled the local address books option.

Comment: I don't want to make suggestions from my local address book, but my g-mail contacts address book.

Comment: In my case, I have 3 address books: one is default personal address book, 2nd is g-mail contacts and 3rd from external crm system. All of them are local address books, even if g-mail contacts are also stored in google. So in TB, you have to enable this option and then it is looking in all your local address books.

Comment: This did the trick for me.